# Are vendor-specific USB serial adapters supported in Metro apps?

Tags: serial-port, microsoft-metro, usb, windows-8.1, usbserial

There's a sample provided for CDC compliant USB devices [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/USB-CDC-Control-sample-5ba19caa/view/Discussions). Are vendor-specific USB devices supported too? Or are CDC compliant USB devices the only ones supported in Metro apps?

Your help is much appreciated!!

Comment: it looks like you missed a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vendor specific USB to UART bridge devices will not be supported under CDC, only a USB CDC class device would be supported in that case.

However, since Microsoft has opened up a USB API you could still access vendor specific devices. The downside here is that the devices will not look like a COM port, you would need to use the [Windows.Devices.Usb namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.usb.aspx) to access the device directly through it's USB protocol. This means that the vendor for a specific device would need to publish their protocol, or you could reverse engineer or use the Linux source as an example of what the setup packets for certain commands should look like.

Since you're using an FTDI converter you can get the device protocol information from their [Linux Source (this is from 3.13 kernel)](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.c?id=refs/tags/v3.13) and use this to access the device through Windows RT.

Comment: I have a requirement that the device must recognized over a serial port and not USB. :( Any other ways for my Metro app to communicate over a serial port and not over USB?

Comment: At the moment I don't think so. You're in driver territory that is restricted on the Windows RT OS at the moment. It wasn't until just recently that they opened up the USB API I mentioned above. What type of USB-serial converter are you using?

Comment: Shucks I'm sorry if I'm not answering your question correctly. Its driver details are:
ausbmon.sys
ftdibus.sys
ftbusui.dll
ftd2xx.dll
FTLang.dll
ftd2xx.dll

It supports USB2.0, FT-232R.

Comment: Update answer to show the source code location, you're using an FTDI converter. Check the Linux source for the USB packets.

Answer (score 1):

FTDI might support Win RT in the future (today is 2014-Apr-15), you can ask for a beta driver here:
[Windows RT Driver](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/WindowsRT.htm)